# PHP moving gif image between two place over time

Tags: php, layout, gif

I have a gif animation image, and on my page, I want to move that animation between two places. for example, it will display left of page for 3 seconds, then move to right side of page and display for 3 seconds, and come back to left of page, keep repeating in this way.

I am new at PhP and website things, so I wish if anyone could give me a clue.
simple code example would be nice if possible.

Thanks in advance!
:)

Comment: You'd need to do this in JavaScript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can animate image movements in screen by using Javascript and css. But not in PHP.

So here is the demo tutorial link. [Code](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/image-move1.php) &  [Demo](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/image-move1-demo.php)
Here is the code.

```js
function reset1() {
  clearTimeout(my_time);
  document.getElementById('i1').style.left = "500px";
  document.getElementById('i1').style.top = "100px";
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";

}



function move_img(str) {

  var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
  x = x + 100;
  document.getElementById('i1').style.top = x + "px";

}

function disp() {
  var step = 1; // Change this step value
  //alert("Hello");
  var y = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
  if (y < 600) {
    y = y + step;
    document.getElementById('i1').style.top = y + "px"; // vertical movment
  } else {
    if (x < 800) {
      x = x + step;
      document.getElementById('i1').style.left = x + "px"; // horizontal movment
    }
  }
  //////////////////////

}

function timer() {
  disp();
  var y = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "X: " + x + " Y : " + y
  my_time = setTimeout('timer()', 10);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demo of Image moving across screen in JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src=http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/images/help.jpg id='i1' style="position:absolute; left: 500; top: 100;">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type=button onClick=timer() value='Start'>
  <input type=button onClick=reset1() value='Reset'>
  <div id='msg'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see. I can put javascript inside php, I saw php sources codes which include javascript almost everywhere. am I right?

Comment: The OP doesn't have [enough rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to vote you up yet.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. This is better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Js  Try this one. save this code as html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.divmain{ width:1000px; height:400px; margin:0 auto;}
.divmain .left{ float:left; width:200px; height:200px;} 
.divmain .right{ float:right; width:200px; height:200px; display:none} 
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
      $('.left').toggle();
      $('.right').toggle();                

}, 5000);

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="divmain">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/4.gif" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/4.gif" width="200" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```